# Textarea value not appearing on $_POST object

Tags: php, forms, post, textarea, submit

Guys, im scratching my head around this one.

I have [this website](http://ihc.wsbp.eu) that basically contains a few forms that are filled in by the user. The user then can download that information in human readable format (pdf) or machine readable format (xml) but I'm having a slight problem submitting textboxes.

I have a few of them, for instance in the description section, but when i access the $_POST['Desc_Desc_desc'] value, it's empty even though i can see content on the textarea. The weird thing is that when i use firebug to inspect the element, it shows the element as if it had no contents..

Can anyone figure what is causing this strange behavior?

Comment: simply debug with var_dump($_POST) and make sure your form has attributes method="post" and action set. AFAIK firebug doesn't show content of the input fields.

Comment: Are you accessing the id or the name? because I see they're different

Comment: Well, the form has the method="post" attribute and the action is set dynamically by javascript. I'm accessing the field using the name attribute and here is the var_dump result:

array(4) { ["Desc_Desc_name"]=> string(3) "SAD" ["Desc_Desc_keywords"]=> string(3) "SAD" ["Desc_Desc_concept"]=> string(14) "HTTP://URL.COM" ["Desc_Desc_desc"]=> string(0) "" }

So, there is an entry for the textarea field (Desc_Desc_desc) but its empty for some reason

Comment: Try `<textarea id... name..> value goes here </textarea> (not using value="", I mean)`

Comment: thanks @DamienPirsy i used your answer, if it would be in answer portion i really would be up voting....thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `service_level_library.buttons.prepForSubmit`, the textarea is cloned along with the rest of the form via the DOM [`cloneNode`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-3A0ED0A4) method. This copies HTML element attributes, but not DOM properties. (Sometimes DOM element node properties have a [corresponding attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-642250288), so updating the property affects the attribute, which can make it appear that DOM properties are being copied.)

While [textarea DOM objects](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-24874179) have a [`value` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-70715579), the [textarea HTML element](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/forms.html#h-17.7) doesn't have a corresponding `value` attribute, so the `value` property isn't exposing an attribute. Thus when you clone the node, the (empty) `value` attribute is what gets copied, leaving the [current value](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/forms.html#current-value) of the element (as accessible via the `value` property) behind.

To fix your script, do one of:

1. Copy the value after cloning.
2. Set the [initial value](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/forms.html#initial-value) for the textarea, either by assigning to the [`defaultValue`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-36152213) property or setting the text content of the node, before cloning. This works because the current value of the cloned node will be set to its initial value, and a deep copy of a textarea will copy its text contents (the source of its initial value).
3. Programmatically replace the textarea with an input before cloning (though this would be more involved than the other options),

Comment: I think you might be right! I do clone the all the forms that are hidden on a background div to a new form to submit. If clone doesn't copy the value that explains why the textareas are empty.

Answer (score 0):

You say in your question `$_POST['Desc_Desc_desc']`, although in the code I see a textarea with name `Dep_desc` and id `Dep_Desc_Desc`. Then you should write `$_POST['Dep_desc']`, i.e. the `name` of the `<textarea>` instead of the `id`.

Also, `textarea`s don't have a `value` attribute, so in your html you should write the initial content between the opening and the closing tag.

**HTML**

```
<textarea name="Dep_desc" id="Dep_Desc_Desc">Initial content</textarea>
```

**PHP**

```
echo "The content of the textarea is ".nl2br(htmlspecialchars($_POST['Dep_desc']));
```

**notes**

`nl2br`: Respect new lines in the html output replacing the `\n` symbol with `<br />`.

`htmlspecialchars`: Prevent possible [`XSS`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks.

Comment: There are multiple textareas in the page, the Desc_Desc_desc is for the sub-section Description, the Dep_desc you refer is for the sub-section Dependability so we're talking about different textareas.

I've already removed the value attribute, don't know why i had it there in the first place, i'm using the name attribute to access it in the POST object and the result is still the same..

Halp!

Answer (score 0):

I used firebug to analyze what gets sent to your script by

```
document.getElementById('descriptionForm').submit()
```

The form data is being sent correctly

> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded Content-Length: 113
>
> Desc_Desc_name=SO&Desc_Desc_keywords=overflow&Desc_Desc_concept=http%3A%2F%2Fso.com&Desc_Desc_desc=Stack+overflow

1. The form action parameter is currently set to "submit.action" which yields a 404.
2. The form buttons are defined outside your form tag.
3. The form buttons does not activate a submit on your form.

Bottom line: the form does not get submitted to the intended recipient.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but later I found out that somewhere at the bottom, I had reused the same name for another element which was empty. That wiped off my required element at var_dump, print_r as well.  It took a while to get that out.