# Why the text contained in textarea is not coming in the $_POST array in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I've following HTML form:

```
<form name="question_issue_form" id="question_issue_form" class="login_box" method="post" action="{$site_url}question_issue.php">
      <input type="hidden" name="form_submitted" id="form_submitted" value="yes"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="post_url" id="post_url" value="question_issue.php"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="op" id="op" value="question_issue"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="question_id" id="question_id" value="{$question_id}"/>

      <table class="trnsction_details" width="100%" cellpadding="5">
        <tbody>    
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
              <input type="checkbox" name = "que_issue[]" value = "Question is wrong" id ="chkQueWrong">Question is wrong</input>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name = "que_issue[]" value = "Answers are wrong" id ="chkAnsWrong">Answers are wrong</input></td> 
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name = "que_issue[]" value = "Question direction is incorrect" id ="chkDirIncorrect">Question direction is incorrecct</input></td>                
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name = "que_issue[]" value = "Other" id ="chkOther">Other</input></td>          
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td class="set_message" style="display:none;"><textarea name="que_issue_comment" id = "que_issue_comment" rows="4" cols="25" maxlength="100"></textarea></td>      
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="report_question_issue" class="c-btn submit_form"/></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </form>
```

I'm submitting the form using AJAX. When I print the `$_POST[]` array I'm able to get all the values entered by user, values from hidden fields, etc. except the text from the textarea having name que_issue_comment. Can anyone guide me why such thing is happening? For your reference I'm putting below the AJAX code I've written.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("click","input[id='chkOther']", function (e) { 
  $('.set_message').toggle(this.checked);
});
$(document).on('click', "input[id='report_question_issue']", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    //for confirmation that status change
    var ans = confirm("Are you sure to report the question issue?");
    if (!ans) { 
      return false;
    }
var post_url = $('#post_url').val();
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: post_url,
        data: $('#question_issue_form').serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
          var error = data.error_message;
          if(error)
            alert(error);
          else {
            alert("Question issue has been reported successfully.");
            $.colorbox.close();
          }
        }
      });
    });

</script>
```

The array `$_POST[]` printed after form submission is as follows:

```
(
    [form_submitted] => yes
    [post_url] => http://localhost/abc/pqr/web/question_issue.php
    [op] => question_issue
    [question_id] => 77104
    [que_issue_comment] => 
)
```

Why the index value `[que_issue_comment]` is coming blank even after filling up the text area?

Comment: Why does the element containing text area have style display:none? Are you using text area as a hidden element?

Comment: Your `textarea` has style `display:none`

Comment: @ng-jslearningcurve:Yes, initially the textarea is hidden. It only displays when the checkbox is checked. I've added the javascript code to the question please look at it.

Comment: You are not filling anything in textarea. Otherwise this code is okay.

Comment: Please before submitting fill the `textarea` with text and add a `console.log($('#question_issue_form').serialize())` to see what is being sent

Comment: @RohitAwasthi:I'm filling the textarea with text but I'm not getting the text I entered after submission of form.

Comment: I can't see anything apparent either. Textare is enclosed in the form and I presume it is filled correctly. Try looking at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250360/textarea-value-not-appearing-on-post-object

Comment: After you check the checkbox, do you see the Textarea?. Just inspect that so it reflects in DOM. Check the name attribute.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RjKMQ/, see this is just your code and its working. Can you create jsfiddle of your non-working Code?

Comment: @RohitAwasthi:How did you check the values contained in $_POST in above jsFiddle?

Comment: just checked "Form Data" in chrome console.

Comment: Try getting the data from text area by getting it's innerhtml. The text area does not have a "value" you can't treat it as input type text. I think your data is ignored because it is not a standard input type element.

Comment: Actually I tried this in my local server. I am able to get the textarea contents in the $_POST. I tried this by changing `dataType` to 'text'.

Comment: @PHPLover This code worked fine for me just like the way it is above. You would need to reproduce this problem to us some other way.

Comment: Can you post your actual php code that receives and outputs the submission?